# Creating graph using dictionaries and nodes only

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, nodes

I have this data.

```
CITY1     CITY2
A         B
A         C
A         D
B         C
B         D
C         D
```

How i can create dictionary looking like this from the above data

```
x={A:[B,C,D],
   B:[A,C,D],
   C:[A,B,D],
   D:[A,B,C]
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do it without any library import.
I made a simple dictionary first .

```
x={'A':['B','C','D'],'B':['C','D'],'C':['D']}
for i,j in x.items():
    for p in j:
        if p not in x.keys():
                x[p]=[]
        if p in x[i] and i not in x[p]:
                x[p].append(i)
print x
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'C': ['D', 'A', 'B'], 'B': ['C', 'D', 'A'], 'D': ['A', 'C', 'B']}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't want redundant edges, so you should use sets instead of lists.

Answer (score 2):

Is it in a csv?  It looks like, from the data you provide, you are doing an undirected graph.  Assuming that the data is in some kind of "row" type format that you can loop through, (i.e. row[0] is the city1 value, and row[1] is the city2 value):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_graph(data):
    graph = defaultdict(set)
    for a, b in data:
        graph[a].add(b)
        graph[b].add(a)  # delete this line if you want a directed graph
    return graph

data = [
  ['A','B'],
  ['C','D'],
  ['A','C']
]

print make_graph(data)
```